# Switching between Java Runtime environments

Tags: environment-variables, java

I have both Java 6 and Java 7 installed in my computer running Windows XP sp3. I have entered path in the environment variables (PATH, JAVA_HOME) in My computer-> Properties. But when I give

> java -version

I still get the following text

> java version "1.7.0_09" 
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_09-b05) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

However, when I try

> javac -version

I get

> javac 1.6.0_03

How can I change the runtime from Java 7 to Java 6? When I compile my program in eclipse using ant, I get the following

> Warning: java\util\List.class(java\util:List.class): major version 51
>   is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this
>   compiler. [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.

Comment: What does it say when you type `echo %PATH%`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Path has the JRE first, thus the `java -version` and the JDK second, thus the `javac -version`. Check your PATH variable.

If you want the JDK version, put it first on the PATH.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. 
I always add the %JAVA_HOME%\bin; as the first argument on the PATH. This way I only need to edit JAVA_HOME to switch between JDKs.

Comment: Didn't work immediately, had to modify the System variables and not the "current user" variable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If am not mistake java 7 windows installer of JDK or JRE will copy java.exe to some windows common path. I don't remember exactly the path but maybe C:\Windows\System32. Try this on command line to know where is the location of java.exe:

```
where java
```

Update your path precedence accordingly.

Comment: Not sure in windows xp, but it work in Windows 7. You just can try. It similar with 'which' command in unix.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Java (JRE), it copies `java.exe` into `C:\Windows\System32`, in addition to installation directory under `C:\Program Files`. But when you install full JDK (with compiler), it doesn't do that for `javac.exe`. When you have multiple versions of java, the last installed one will be called when you type `java` in command line.

Use full paths if you need to have multiple Java versions, you will always have problems trying to use unqualified `java` in command line. Alternatively, re-install JRE 7 - that will force default `java` to be V7.